# How to disable test cases in JMeter non-GUI?

Tags: testing, jmeter

If I run a test suite, it will run all the test cases inside it (i.e. 30 test cases). But how to disable some of the test cases so I just run 20 test cases instead of 30 test cases in that test suite for example. Is there any command to do it?

Comment: Do you mean inside JUnit Sampler? Can you add more details?

Comment: @user7294900 no, not JUnit Sampler. I run jmeter -n -t D:\Test\TestCase01\script.jmx, then this will run single test. I managed to run the test suite (until TestCase20). How do I run the test suite (from TestCase01 to TestCase20) EXCEPT TestCase04 & TestCase05 for example. How I am going to disable both TestCase04 & TestCase05.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-load-test-parts-with-the-jmeter-if-controller/) as a parent for each TestCase

> Add the property `${__P(do_the_search,0)} == 1`  to the If Controller:

[image]

> in order to run the script with the search part of the script turned on, we simply pass this command to the console:
>
> ```
> jmeter -n -t <test-name> -Jdo_the_search=1
> ```

Comment: Do you know how to execute it without going inside the GUI? How to disable it directly using script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in order to determine the path to the test plan

```
${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir().contains('TestCase04'),)}
```

To include 2 clauses:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir().contains('TestCase04') || org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir().contains('TestCase05'),)}
```

You can use the above functions directly in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) like:

```
${__groovy(if (org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir().contains('TestCase04') || org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir().contains('TestCase05')) {return '0'} else {return '100'},)}
```

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thank you, but is there any command to disable any test cases inside the test suite so that I can directly run it without the GUI?